# How to dynamically change date format based on country

Tags: javascript, reactjs

The React application I'm working on is targeting US and Canadian users. As of my understanding, Canadians use dd/mm/yyyy format, and US uses mm/dd/yyyy. Is there a way to dynamically change the date format based on which country the user is using the app in?

Comment: isn't this what [toLocaleDateString](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleDateString) is for?

Answer (score 1):

use `Date.toLocaleDateString()` it returns date using using locale conventions(users computer)